# Constructing a tower to the splitting field of an arbitrary irreducible cubic.

Tags: galois-theory

Let f(x) = x<sup>3</sup> + ax<sup>2</sup> + bx + c ∈ $\mathbb{Q}$[x].  Let K be the splitting field of f(x).  I want to construct a tower: 
$\mathbb{Q}$ ⊂ K<sub>1</sub> ⊂ ... ⊂ K<sub>r</sub> = K

Each K<sub>i</sub> = K<sub>i-1</sub>(α) where either α<sup>2</sup> ∈ K<sub>i</sub> or α<sup>3</sup> ∈ K<sub>i</sub>.

I figured my first step should be to extend by a primitive nth root of unity first, and then work from there.

Comment: I would check out the chapter on Galois theory in Artin. He goes through the details of the cubic as well as solvability by radicals.

Comment: You could also check Dummit & Foote's chapter on solvability by radicals, it is also very detailed. Artin's book suggested by jgon is great too.

Comment: Actually now that I think about it, Artin proves Cardano's formula, which seems to be (basically) what you want.

Comment: Agree with jgon. The quantities $u$ and $v$ in Cardano's method (see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/157746/11619) for an on-site explanation) have cubes that are contained in a quadratic extension. That's essentially the tower you need (throw the thid roots of unity to the mix).

Comment: Reading more carefully: You need the third roots of unity to get that root tower. But the splitting field may not need them! Works as prescribed only over $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$.

Comment: For example the splitting field of the polynomial $x^3-3x+1$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ is the cubic real field $K=\Bbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi/9))$ which clearly cannot be achieved as a root tower extension. OTOH $K(e^{2\pi i/3})=\Bbb{Q}(e^{2\pi i/9})$ clearly is a root tower extension.