# Cubic Depressed Form ! What can we deduce form it?

Tags: roots, cubics

Cubic depressed form with equation $f(x) = x^3 + px + q$

The question is, when $p$ is positive, will the function have $3$ real roots ? or does it have to have $1$ real and $2$ complex roots?

My question is not the same as 
[Maths cubic equation discriminant....](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1371510/maths-cubic-equation-discriminant)

I need to know the possibilities of roots when p is positive.

Comment: see herehttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function

Comment: they didnt say anything about (p)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maths cubic equation discriminant....](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1371510/maths-cubic-equation-discriminant)

Comment: @yvesdaoust HI, the questions are not the same. I want to know different possibilities of roots according to different values of p. In the previous post, it is not answered and is merely asking the origin of the discriminant,

Comment: *What can we deduce form it ?* - That all those sad little cubics are in need of some serious anti-depressants ? :-$($

Answer (score 2):

We have $f'(x) = 3x^2+p \ge p > 0 $. Consequently, $f$ is strictly increasing.

- $f(x)=0$ has at most one real solution. Otherwise take two distinct real solution $x_1<x_2$. Since $f$ is strictly increasing we have $0=f(x_1)<f(x_2)=0$. Absurd.
- Since 
  $$\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x) = +\infty,\quad\text{and }\quad \lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x) = -\infty.$$ 
  The function $f$ is continuous and $f(x)$ goes from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ when $x$ goes from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. By continuity, $f(x)$ has to take the value $0$ at least once.

Finally, there is exactly one solution to the equation $f(x)=0$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes, but that is only for the extrema. If p is positive, there will not be any min or max so the function can only have 1 real 2 complex or 1 triple roots? Is that correct? Did I miss any possibilities?

Comment: Your question is about positive $p$.

Comment: sorry typo.    i am confused. Please look at this page http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1371510/maths-cubic-equation-discriminant . It says p has to be negative in order to let 2 extrema to occur. So I am not sure...

Comment: @TommyLassa If there is something you don't understand [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1371510/maths-cubic-equation-discriminant), you may ask for clarification there. Or you can ask a different question about this specific point.

Comment: Yes, but it is a different question. I want to know the different possibilities of cubic roots according to different value of p. My previous post merely explain the origin of discriminant.

Comment: Now that I've developed my answer, you understand why in the case where $p>0$, the function $f$ has $1$ real root and $2$ complex roots?

Comment: sorry I dont understand anything you write :( sorry. May you guide me a little bit?

Comment: You don't understand _anything_ I write? I find it hard to believe. Please tell me _precisely_ what you don't understand.

Comment: wait I understand :). so when p is negative, cubic can have multiple roots?

Comment: What about $f(x)=x^3-x$ for example? Or $f(x)=x^3$?

Comment: so they are some special cases? what is special about x^3-x? p is -1 so we know it has to have 3 real roots.  But when p and q are zero there will be 1 triple roots ?