# Solve a Linear System

Tags: matrices

Trying to solve the linear system below for $x,y$ and $z$ in terms of $a,b,c$ and $\zeta_3$:

$x+y+z=a$

$x+{\zeta_3}y+{\zeta_3}z=b$

$x+{\zeta_3}^2y+{\zeta_3}^2z=c$

where $\zeta_3=-1/2+-i(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2})$ i.e. ${\zeta_3}^3=1$

From a book by the Russian author Smirnoff (translated by Silverman) - the author says the answer is $x=(a+b+c)/3$; $y=(a+b{\zeta_3}^2+c{\zeta_3})/3$; $z=(a+b{\zeta_3}+c{\zeta_3}^2)/3$

Got part of the way with Gaussian elimination, but couldn’t figure out how to use the information about e to finish the solution.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Please use MathJax to typeset the equations.

Comment: Let me write $\zeta_3$ for $e$, because $e$ is Euler's number. You only need that $1+\zeta_3+\zeta_3^2=0$ and $\zeta_3^3=1$.

Comment: If that is the solution, then the equations are wrong. You need both $\zeta_3$ and $\zeta_3^2$ appear as coefficients in the two latter equations. In which case it is an instance of inverting a discrete Fourier transform. And the solution can be verified using Dietrich's hint.

Comment: See [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/158152/11619) for the correct triple of equations.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a few steps of Gauss elimination you can get
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & 1 & a\\
1 & \zeta_3 & \zeta_3 & b\\
1 & \zeta_3^2 & \zeta_3^2 & c
\end{array}\right]\begin{array}{l}
\\
F_2\leftarrow F_2-F_1\\
F_3\leftarrow F_3-F_1\\
\end{array}
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & 1 & a\\
0 & \zeta_3-1 & \zeta_3-1 & b-a\\
0 & \zeta_3^2-1 & \zeta_3^2-1 & c-a
\end{array}\right]$$
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\ \\
\ \\
F_3\leftarrow F_3-(\zeta_3+1)F_2
\end{array}\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & 1 & a\\
0 & \zeta_3-1 & \zeta_3-1 & b-a\\
0 & 0 & 0 & c-a -(\zeta_3+1)(b-a)
\end{array}\right]$$
So, Rouché tells you that the system only has solution if
\begin{equation}
c-a-(\zeta_3+1)(b-a)=0,\tag{1}
\label{eq:abc}
\end{equation}
and in that case there are infinite solutions. Then, call $z=\lambda$, and the solutions are:
$$x=a-\frac{b-a}{\zeta_3-1},\quad y=\frac{b-a}{\zeta_3-1}-\lambda,\quad z=\lambda,\quad\forall\lambda\in\mathbb{C}.$$
If you use the relation \eqref{eq:abc} I think that it can be shown that one of the solutions is exactly the answer you have, but obviously there are (infinitely) many more.

I just read in a comment from Jyrki Lahtonen that the equations may have an error. That is likely to be the case.

Comment: I got to the point shown in Gaussian elimination above.  You were right ... book had mistakes in equations 2 and 3 that I should’ve caught.  Thx so much.