# How to factor polynomial with irrational roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let's say I have the equation 2x^4 + 4x^3 -72x^2 + 24x and I want to factor it. Obviously one of the roots is zero, but the other 3 roots are all irrational. Is there a way to factor for irrational roots? If so could you explain how to factor for those roots?

Comment: You've heard of the quadratic formula I expect... well, there are also similar (*but increasingly more complicated*) formulas for cubics and quartics as well.  Most people don't bother memorizing them and are satisfied just knowing that such a formula exists that they could look up if they ever need it.  Importantly, you should also be made aware that no such formula exists for a quintic or above... not because such a formula hasn't been found  yet but rather that it has been proven that no such generic formula could exist that works for all cases using only radicals.

Comment: See [General cubic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#General_cubic_formula), see [General quartic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_equation#The_general_case), and finally see [Abel-Ruffini theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem) for unsolvability of the quintic.  Additionally, I recommend [this youtube video by Mathologer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-KXStupwsc) for history and a derivation on the cubic formula that is easy to follow and entertaining.

Comment: [An older related thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/157746/11619). I happened to answer that, so I won't jump to try and  use it as duplicate target. For one, it is specific to cubics (which happens to be enough for your particular example).