# How to factorize the polynomial $x^4+3x^2+x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

$$x^4+3x^2+x=0$$

I only can think of

$$x(x^3+3x+1)$$

I don't know what else to do if substitution fails and also RRT.

Is this solvable?

or we have to use imaginary solutions?

Comment: There is a cubic formula you can look up to factor $x^3+3x+1$

Comment: [A local discussion explaining Cardano's cubic formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/157746/11619). RRT implies that the cubic is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$ but obviously it has a single real root, and hence it factors further over the reals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a precalculus level, that's as far as you can factorise it. As [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%5E3%2B3x%2B1) demonstrates, the cubic component has one real root at

$$x = \sqrt[3]{\frac{\sqrt{5} - 1}{2}} - \sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{\sqrt{5} - 1}}$$

as well as two complex roots, but finding any of those requires [a bit of algebraic trickery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Derivation_of_the_roots).